# Python Selenium geckodriver required in path

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/bin/python/DLX/geckodriver': '/home/ubuntu/bin/python/DLX/geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckoPath,options=options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

The above is the error I am getting while trying to use geckodriver and selenium. Geckodriver is in the path /home/ubuntu/bin/python/DLX/, that path has been added to the PATH var and I can see it when using echo $PATH. Below is the code I'm trying to get running.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from sys import platform


# setting browser to be heaadless
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
#Telling it where to find the required file
currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
geckoPath = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(currentDir,'geckodriver'))
print(geckoPath)
binary = FirefoxBinary(geckoPath)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckoPath,options=options)
```

I've looked at other posts, tried their fixes and I've still got the issue. Running it on RPI3b+ Ubuntu server if that helps.
Selenium Ver=3.141.0
geckodriver ver=v0.23.0

Edit:
PATH is as follows
/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin/python/DLX

Comment: It is unable to detect geckodriver make sure you did right installation and set appropriate path

Comment: The folder containing gecko is in PATH, as stated in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It would be fine if you create once driver folder in you project and place geckodriver there and provide path as mentioned below.

Lets say folder name is `drivers`

```
firefox_driver = "/drivers/geckodriver"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_driver,options=options)
```

Comment: Editied it to try using this and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what ' facing by u' means?

Comment: I mean after using the way i posted, Is it showing same error or this time error is different

Comment: The error is the same, only difference being the directory it mentions.